# Printing upto a specific string when reading from a file in php

Tags: php

I have a text file containing names which i am reading using the file() function in php but when i am trying to stop at certain point when a matching name is found, i am not getting any output. please help.

```
<?php 
    $data = file('names.txt');
    foreach($data as $val){
       if($val == "Amanda jackson"){
           break;
       }else{
           echo $val;
       }
    }
    
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean "you get no output". Could it be that if you find `$val == "Amanda jackson` You dont generate any output?

Comment: If you also showed us at least some of the `names.txt` file maybe we could be even more help

Comment: If you are getting "Absolutely No Output" Could it be that `Amanda jackson` is the first name in the file

Comment: here are the list of the names :- Abigail smith
Alexandra rose
Alison reed
Amanda jackson
Amelia wood
what i want is to print the names which are before Amanda jackson and not the names after Amanda

Comment: Please edit your question to include any new info you provide, thats where people look for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `rtrim()` to remove the newline from `$val`

```
$data = file('names.txt');
foreach($data as $val){
    if(rtrim($val) == 'Amanda jackson'){
        //if you want to print Amada's name add an echo here
        break;
    }else{
        echo $val;
    }
}
```